# MySQL: Pulling and presenting information from multiple tables, based on user input

Tags: mysql, database

I am a bit out of my depth when it comes to SQL programming, but after searching for a solution to my problem I do not find any relevant answers, hence my question here:

Using MySQL, I have a table called newsletter_subscriber. This table contains only a list of email addresses (subscriber_email), each row of email addresses with a unique ID (subscriber_ID), the ID being incremented by 1 for each row.

What I would like to accomplish is to be able to type in a "from" ID, and a "to" ID (e.g. from 672 to 835), and for each of these have the tables sales_flat_order_address and sales_flat_order_address queried for the respective email address to return the First name of the customer (firstname) and the Last name (lastname) along with the Telephone number (telephone).

The only thing the three tables (newsletter_subscriber, tables sales_flat_order_address and sales_flat_order_address) have in common is the email address. If a match is found in either sales_flat_order_address and sales_flat_order_address, further search for this email address should be abandoned so we do not end up with multiple results for the same email address (both table may contain the same email address, and each table may even contain the email address multiple times, in all cases the full information of firstname, lastname and telephone will be present).

The end result should look something like this (my comments below):

```
1:  2:                      3:          4:          5:
672 email1@example.com      Firstname1  Lastname1   Telephone1
673 email2@example.com      Firstname2  Lastname2   Telephone2
674 email3@example.com      Firstname3  Lastname3   Telephone3
675 email4@example.com      Firstname4  Lastname4   Telephone4
676 email5@example.com      Firstname5  Lastname5   Telephone5
..  ..                      ..  ..  ..
835 email174@example.com    Firstname6  Lastname6   Telephone6
```

*1: Column 1, showing the incremented ID from the manually input subscriber_id column from table newsletter_subscriber

*2: Column 2, showing the respective field subscriber_email from table newsletter_subscriber

*3: Column 3, showing the respective field firstname from tables sales_flat_order_address or sales_flat_order_address, to correspond with the respective email address in column 2

*4: Column 4, showing the respective field lastname from tables sales_flat_order_address or sales_flat_order_address, to correspond with the respective email address in column 2

*5: Column 5, showing the respective field telephone from tables sales_flat_order_address or sales_flat_order_address, to correspond with the respective email address in column 2

Could anyone be so kind as to contribute a code example?

Comment: What do you mean by manually? Manually where?

Comment: Ooops, I believed it would be possible to get a prompt for user input. Come to think of it, this may not be possible with normal SQL programming, even though my SQL database handling program (Navicat) does offer this option. Maybe this is a Navicat-specific feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```
SELECT t1.`subscriber_email`, t2.`firstname`, t2.`lastname`, t2.`telephone` from `newsletter_subscriber` t1 JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` t2 on
t1.`subscriber_email` = t2.`email`
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit. This solved the core "problem" that I had, and using your code as a base, I was able to expand it to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select ns.email, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.telephone from sales_flat_order_address a inner join newsletter_subscriber ns on
a.subscriber_ID = ns.ID
```

This should work given that your tables have the following fields:
sales_flat_order_address: email, firstname, lastname, telephone, subscriber_ID
newsletter_subscriber: ID, email

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but to me (as a newbee), it seems you are depending on the same IDs being present in both tables newsletter_subscriber and sales_flat_order_address? This is not the case. The only common denominator is the email address.